# Newlines not working in PHP?

Tags: php, newline

This is my complete web page, with php code taken directly from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).  Yet all the text on the page renders on a single line?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

echo "This spans
multiple lines. The newlines will be
output as well";

echo "This spans\nmultiple lines. The newlines will be\noutput as well.";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML does not support newlines, therefore you must use `<br>`.

You could use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) which will convert all your `\n` in your string, to `<br>` which will generate your desired output.

Comment: @Anthony- <br> works- but I'm still mystified as to why regular \n newlines won't, considering it's straight out of the docs?

Comment: @Yarin: That is unrelated to the real reason why you're not seeing multiple lines in your pages.

Answer (score 3):

The newlines are there in your source code. Browsers, however, won't render newlines as line breaks on your page, so you need to use line break tags (`<br />`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

HTML will coalesce consecutive whitespace (in most contexts) to a single space character. You'll either need to output paragraphs (`<p>...</p>`) or other tags with border or padding, or output explicit line-breaks (`<br>`).

Answer (score 1):

The newlines do indeed get printed, but HTML does not care about whitespace (unless you explicitly tell it to, look at `pre` element and `white-space: pre`).

Browsers will essentially turn all `\s` into one space when viewing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the new lines are there and they are working. Take a gander at the HTML ***source*** (i.e when you right-click on the browser and select *View Page Source*) and not the results being displayed in the browser. You'll see the new lines there.

The problem is that HTML itself does not care about how you format your white space. To HTML all white space, whether a tab, a new line, or a whole mess of spaces is translated as a single space.

To get HTML to display line breaks, you'll have to use HTML tags such as `<pre>`, `<p>`, or `<br/>`.

I find it easier in PHP programs to create my own `echoLine` function that adds in both the `\n` and a `<br/>`. That way, I see it in both the webpage source and the HTML display.